# Write MapReduce function to count number of posts created by various users in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, nosql

I had created a collection "posts" with title, description, by, comments in MongoDB as:

```
db.posts.insert({
                  title:'MongoDB',
                  description:'MongoDB is a NoSQL DB',
                  by:'Tom',
                  comments:[
                             {user:'ram',
                               message:'We use MongoDB'
                             }
                           ]
                }
               )
```

Similarly, I added other two entries.
 Now, I want to write *MapReduce function to count number of posts created by various users* in MongoDB. I used:

```
db.posts.mapReduce( 
   function() { emit(this.user_id,1); }, 
   function(key, values) {return Array.sum(values)}, {    
      out:"post_total" 
   }

).find()
```

This Output:

```
{"id": null , "value": 3}
```

But, what I want to display is something like:

```
{ "_id" : "tom_id", "value" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "mark_id", "value" : 1 }
```

or

```
{ "by" : "tom", "value" : 2 }
{ "by" : "mark", "value" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solve it. I got some idea from [MapReduce function in MongoDB - Grouping document by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121550/mapreduce-function-in-mongodb-grouping-document-by-id?rq=1)

```
db.posts.mapReduce( 
   function() { emit(this.by,1); }, 
   function(key, values) {return Array.sum(values)}, {    
      out:"post_total" 
   }

).find()
```

What I doing wrong was, emit(this.*user_id*,1). I was passing the wrong key.

Answer (score 0):

Re-write your mapReduce method to:

```
db.posts.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(this.user_id, 1);
    },
    function(key, values) {
        return Array.sum(values);
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

or use the runCommand command to run a mapReduce operation with an output collection option:

```
mr = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce": "posts",
    "map" : function() {
        for (var key in this) { emit(this.user_id, 1); }
    },
    "reduce" : function(key, values) { return Array.sum(values); }, 
    "out": "post_total"
})
```

To get the results, run `find()` on the resulting collection:

```
db[mr.result].find()
```

---

Equivalent results yet much more efficient operation using the aggregation framework:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$user_id",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: db.posts.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(this.user_id, 1);
    },
    function(key, values) {
        return Array.sum(values);
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
).find()

Output: 

[{"id": null , "value": 3}]

Does not work.

Comment: @SarojShrestha Why are you appending find() to an inline output?

Comment: without find() output 
 "results" :[
                  { "id":null,
                      "value":3
                  }
]
"timeMillis":15,
"counts":{
                "input":3,
                 "emit":3,
                  "reduce":3,
                   "output":1
                   },
"ok":1
}

Comment: @chirdam thanks for your time and effort but it still showing id:null. Actually, this is a query asked in my board exam. As there clearly mentioned to write mapreduce function so I am asking about mapreduce specifically. I had followed https://codeteddy.com/2016/06/21/mongodb-a-brief-introduction/ to create collection. Is there something wrong with this method? But it shows fine with: 'db.posts.find()' but with mapreduce function it keeps on generating id:null.

Comment: @SarojShrestha Have you also tried the other query using `aggregate()` method? What is your MongoDB version? What is the output when you query with just `db.posts.find()`?

Comment: MongoDB version 3.2.9
'db.posts.find()' shows "_id": ObjectID(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx), title,description,by,likes and comments.  Here, "by" refers to author. And also, how can i comment as code in comment section. 'ctrl+k' don't work in comment section

Comment: It's best you add as much information as you can in your question since comments are not for extended chats